# Strong continuity (weak to strong) of $\langle Au,v\rangle=\int u^3 v dx$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am currently trying to figure out the following. If I consider the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}_0$ is it possible to show that the operator given by
$$\langle Au,v\rangle=\int u^3 v dx$$
is strongly (weak to strong) continuous for all $p$? We may assume we are on a bounded Lipschitz domain.
It is possible using the Sobolev embedding theorem but that will then restrict our choices of $p$ based on the dimension. I was told it is possible using the reverse dominated convergence theorem. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I don't see how this is even well defined, in general. The exponents in the Sobolev embedding theorem are sharp, are they not?  So take $p=2$ and dimension $d=7$, then there is a $u \in W^{1,p}_0 \setminus L^3$.  If we take $v=1$ (with appropriate cutoff) then the integral is not finite.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question.  What space(s) are the domain and codomain of $A$?   Where is $v$ supposed to live?

Comment: Concretely, if your domain is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^7$ and $p=2$, take $u(x) = |x|^{-2.4}$.  Let $v$ be any smooth function which is $1$ on some neighborhood of the origin.